# xkb keyboard layout not working on certain software

Tags: linux, gnome, keyboard-layout, xkb, fedora-38

I use a custom keyboard layout which I set up by modifying `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/custom` as follows:

```
default partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "custom" {

    name[Group1]="Italian (custom)";

    ...  // other keys I have edited

    key <RTSH>  { [        Tab ] };
    key <NMLK>  { [     Escape ] };
    
    include "kpdl(dot)"
    include "level3(ralt_switch)"
};
```

In particular I have modified the `Right Shift` to serve as a `Tab` and `Num Lock` to serve as `ESC`.

In most software I use, all the key remaps work as expected.
(This is true also for key-combinations. E.g. `CTRL + new_Z => Undo`)

On some software applications, such as VSCode, the modifications for `Right Shift` and `Num Lock` do not work. (I installed VSCode by using the the official website [@Microsoft](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux#_rhel-fedora-and-centos-based-distributions))

System: Fedora 38, GNOME 44.3, Wayland.